# I want to host videos on Telegram and stream them to viewers/users on my React Web App, how can I do it?

Tags: reactjs, video, telegram, telegram-bot

1. I want to host videos on Telegram somewhere
2. use the telegram api to fetch video and stream it like youtube on my React app
3. I want to create a react app for the same.

please tell me the steps involved to do it.

I tried checking out the telegram api documentation and didn't understand it.

I'm doing this because I want to store videos for long term somewhere and access them on my app, and I don't know where to host videos for free and retreive them via api for playing it like youtube. If you know a platform that provides these features, please let me know.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.